# Microsoft.Bcl.Build installed and packages.confg error

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, unirest

Iam using Nuget packages, Unirest, SkyBiometry api for a face detection application.

I have added the reference to `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` to all the projects in my solution. And yes I have the nuget `packages.config` file in the corresponding directory which is

> H:\Project\Inctv_Embd_Fc_Rcgn_Sm_Final\Inctv_Embd_Fc_Rcgn_Sm\FaceDetection\FaceDetection\packages.config

I have targeted the projects to .net framework 4 Client profile.

Comment: Whats the error? What have you researched?

Comment: Could not locate H:\Project\Inctv_Embd_Fc_Rcgn_Sm_Final\Inctv_Embd_Fc_Rcgn_Sm\FaceDetection\FaceDetection\packages.config;.  Ensure that this project has Microsoft.Bcl.Build installed and packages.config is located next to the project file. This is what I have been getting.

Comment: Where is the project file located?

Comment: @PhilipPittle The solution file is in this path..   H:\Project\Inctv_Embd_Fc_Rcgn_Sm_Final\Inctv_Embd_Fc_Rcgn_Sm\FaceDetection\

Comment: And the project file (`csproj`)?

Comment: @PhilipPittle We don't have a .csproj file,we have only the solution file,which is in the path.. H:\Project\Inctv_Embd_Fc_Rcgn_Sm_Final\Inctv_Embd_Fc_Rcgn_Sm\FaceDetection\

Comment: Are you sure about that?  You said you added the reference to `all the projects in my solution`.  If you have projects, you have project files.  If you are using VB, the project file is vbproj.

Comment: @PhilipPittle We do have a project file for Unirest,which is in the directory H:\Project\Inctv_Embd_Fc_Rcgn_Sm_Final\unirest-net-master\unirest-net\unirest-net and we are using C#,so it is unirest-net.csproj